# Convert base64 image to send as multipart/form-data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch, multipartform-data

There is a system. The frontend is written in react and the backend in java.
On the frontend part, there is an image (base64) and some fields (string) that need to be sent to the server.

**'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'**

I also know that on the backend, the image must have a **MultipartFile** type

I do not understand what format I need to convert the picture to.
**Can you please advise me?**

```
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append( 'image', store.image); // store.image - base64
    formData.append( 'id-number-value', "id"); 
    formData.append( 'id-number-type', "id_card"); 

    fetch('/path', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' },
      body: formData
   } )
   .then((response) => {
      if (response.ok) {
        resolve();
      } else {
        throw new Error(response.message);
      }
   })
   .catch((error) => reject(error));
```

Comment: what you've set should work fine. Are you facing errors with that?

Comment: @DheerajSharma The error is not particularly clear to me. I get 503. But I've gotten this error before when I've had some errors in making a request.

Comment: Have a look at this, and remember if user is selecting a file on some input field in ui then that file will be available on event.target.files[0] https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.geeksforgeeks.org/file-uploading-in-react-js/amp/

Comment: Also if its 503, then its error on server side, check your backend service logs

Comment: No need to base64 encode the image, if its file object and you’ve set it in Form Data, everything else will be handled by fetch/axios

Comment: Given that your backend expects it as multipart and not base64 encoded

Comment: Yes, I understand that, that's exactly the point, I don't understand the correct approach to converting from base64 to the type I need. 
I didn't convert the file to base64, it's the way it was originally.

Comment: What type do you need? Basically from ui the request should go as multipart formdata and then on backend it will be received as multipart form data, on backend you can simply write the variable in the request object to a file and you’ll get your  file. As it will be present in the request in the backend in binary.

Comment: The problem is, I don't have access to the backend and I can't see any logs. I only know that on the backend this image already has MultipartFile type (I guess it's something from Spring)

I also know that the request body type is multipart/form-data

Comment: I don't have an understanding of what MultipartFile type is and what do I need to do to convert my picture to it

Comment: If you’re sure its multipart then this is the way to go. https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.geeksforgeeks.org/file-uploading-in-react-js/amp/    Just pass the file instance from your event to form data and set other fields and send it! One other thing you can try in case you’re facing errors is to change the key image to file. formData.append(‘file’, store.image) and see if that helps

Comment: So what comes out. I don't have the picture upload functionality, but whatever. Lets say I uploaded a picture and got a base64 string, which I just put in formdata and make a request?

Comment: What comes out as in?  You need to be a bit clear with what exactly is happening in your system to get some help. You wanna send the request from UI to backend using fetch, that is the way to go, otherwise from where else you get an image on the UI if user isn’t uploading it. If you’re sending it from node to backend then still you’ll have the file object, just set it in form data and send the request. If your use case is out of these two then please help us understand what exactly you’re trying to achieve. I’m all ears!

Comment: I take a photo. I use react-webcam (https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-webcam) and take a photo. Taking photo method returns a base64 encoded string of the current webcam image. I take a photo, then I take that photo and send it to the backend

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4998908/convert-data-uri-to-file-then-append-to-formdata/5100158

Comment: Read that thread, So you can convert your base 64 string to blob, set it to form data and Everyone’s Happy!! ;)

Comment: Basically this function does all the magic https://stackoverflow.com/a/5100158

Comment: Hmm, the error is still there. Eh, looks like I'll interrogate the backend developers tomorrow. 24 hours to release...

Comment: lol. All the best for a Friday release my friend. May you have a wonderful weekend xD

Comment: Thank you! I hope I don't have to do any emergency fixes this weekend, heh

Comment: In case you need anything, We’re here :D xD

Comment: Were you able  to resolve it? do share you're findings.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the base64 string to a blob first.

```js
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('id-number-value', "id");
formData.append('id-number-type', "id_card");
fetch(store.image)
    .then(res => res.blob()).then(blob => {
        formData.append('image', blob);
        fetch('/path', {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
                },
                body: formData
            })
            .then((response) => {
                if (response.ok) {
                    resolve();
                } else {
                    throw new Error(response.message);
                }
            })
            .catch((error) => reject(error));
    });
```

Comment: `'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'` did the job for me.